# How to obtain the means of sizes of a grouping with a Pandas Dataframe, grouped by another column?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataset like this:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
    'entrytype': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd'],
    'year': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001],
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(raw_data)
```

I want the mean of the number of different *entrytypes* per year (*entrytype* is just for the example, the real dataset has other columns and other names).

Now, if I do: `df.groupby(['entrytype', 'year']).size()` I get the number of the *entrytypes* in a [Pandas Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.html) like this:

```
entrytype  year
a          2000    2
b          2000    1
c          2001    3
d          2001    1
dtype: int64
```

What I need is the mean of these numbers per year, something like this:

```
year
2000    1.5
2001    2
```

I've tried to do that with Pandas for a bit, but wasn't able to group by year because the Series is 1d and therefore does not allow grouping. I ended up doing using a Python dictionary and calculating the mean "by hand", but there must be a better way to do this, using Pandas.

So, how can I do that using the Pandas API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
df.groupby(['entrytype', 'year']).size().groupby(level=1).mean()

year
2000    1.5
2001    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: omg, that was so simple! I knew there had to be a better way, thanks! =)